# Material shader smooth gradient between two colors

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have the following shaders used in a custom material shader in threeJS and applied to metaballs. Positions of each metaballs (2 in this example) are passed to an array `allPos` and they are compared in distance with vertex normal to find the closest one. Its index is used to assign a color `blobColor` which is then passed to the fragment shader.

**vertex shader**

```
uniform vec3 colChoice[2];
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 blobColor;
varying vec3 otherColor;
uniform vec3 allPos[2];
varying float mixScale;

void main() {
   vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
   vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
   float prevdist = 1000000000000000000000000000000.0;

   for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
      float distV = distance(allPos[i],normal.xyz);
      if(distV<prevdist){
         prevdist = distV;
         mixScale = distV;
         blobColor = colChoice[i];
         otherColor = colChoice[i-1];
      }
   }
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
"varying vec3 blobColor;",
"varying vec3 otherColor;",
"varying vec3 vNormal;",
"varying float mixScale;",

void main() {
    finalColor = (0.45*vNormal) + mix(otherColor,blobColor,mixScale);
    gl_FragColor = vec4( finalColor, 1.0 );
}
```

which gives me something like this:

It is a bit rough for now and I would like to apply a dot gradient between
the two colors. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your desired behavior is. What do you mean it's a bit rough? If you want a gradient, just change the value of `mixScale` to gradually change from 0-1.

Comment: the question is redundant with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544638/multicolor-metaballs-with-threejs-and-marchingcubes/49544856?noredirect=1#comment86675976_49544856. I will try to develop there